# Using theorem of logical equivalences to show $p \land (\sim q \lor p) \equiv p$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I'm new to the whole discrete math thing, and I'm having trouble finding any laws to start breaking the statement $p \land (\sim q \lor p) \equiv p$ down into its equivalences laws.

Can I have some help please. here's the chart I'm using
[image]

heres an example of the format I need to answer in.

### **statements       | reason**

~[~p^(pvq)]vq=t  | given
p^(pvq)vq=t      | distributive law
(p^p)v(p^q)vq=t  | distributive law
pv(p^q)vq        | Idempotent law
pvq=t            | Absorption law

Comment: It depends on the axioms you use, but the law of excluded middle says that for any proposition $P, P \lor \lnot P$

Comment: What does this have to do with equivalence relations? I've removed the tag and added a more relevant one.

Comment: Using the laws of natural deduction, you can use the fact that if $Q$ then $P\land Q \rightarrow P$, which means ( for $Q \Leftrightarrow (\lnot q \lor p) )$ that $ p \lor (\lnot q \lor p) = p $, since $(\lnot q \lor p)$ is always true.

Comment: Can you deduce what you wrote into the laws in the chart above

Comment: Use commutativity within the parentheses, and then apply one of the absorption laws.

Comment: Using the **idempotent** and **distributive** laws, you can even derive the **absorption** laws. I added a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{aligned}p\land(\neg q\lor p)&\equiv p&\text{given}\\(p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land p)&\equiv p&\text{distributive law}\\(p\land\neg q)\lor p&\equiv p&\text{idempotent law}\\(p\land\neg q)\lor(p\land T)&\equiv p&\text{identity law}\\p\land(\neg q\lor T)&\equiv p&\text{distributive law}\\p\land T& \equiv p&\text{domination law}\\p&\equiv p&\text{identity law}\end{aligned}$

Comment: I think you understand what I'm getting at, can you look at my latest edits to the post and modify your answer to match the format

Comment: @Slowly_Learning, no problem! (:

Comment: appreciate it!!

Comment: It has been long time but could you please explaining how you get from identity law to distributive law? from $(∧¬)∨(∧)≡$ to $∧(¬∨)≡$ ?

Comment: I'm not getting from one law to another, I'm applying those laws (=: